# Expanding a C macro selectively

Tags: c, macros

I have some code that I want to submit to a VCS, but I don't want to include my debugging code in my submitted file.  I test for a macro around all code I don't want submitted, something like this:

```
#ifdef SPECIAL_DEBUG_FLAG
// code I don't want submitted
#endif
```

I cannot simply include all my debug code in a header file, because it necessarily needs to be interlaced with the code I'd like to submit.

My question is: is there a way to selectively expand only the macro SPECIAL_DEBUG_FLAG, so that its contents get deleted before I submit my code to VCS?  I know gcc has the `-E` flag, which will preprocess everything.  But I don't want it to expand things like `#include` for example.

Comment: If you know you're going to loose these lines soon (right after submitting), why not do that yourself? Any reasonable text editor can be quite good at doing that

Comment: I want to keep these lines though.  I want to continue using them as I make future changes.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but I would consider submitting all the debug code to the VCS, but _not_ submitting the makefile or header file or whatever it is that actually defines `SPECIAL_DEBUG_FLAG`.  So anybody ele who checks out and builds the code will not have the debugging code enabled unless they ask for it.  And then when you truly don't need the debugging code any more you can delete it all and resubmit a clean version of the source code without it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I actually had in mind to begin with, but it turns out I'm not allowed to have the debugging code appear in my submission.

Comment: I know of no specific tool to do this, but with care in the construction of your special sections you could use something like sed to parse the code and omit the sections.  I used to work with someone who put a special comment at the end of every line containing temporary debug code.  He could then simply delete every line containing the special comment.

Comment: Unifdef is exactly what I was looking for!  If you could make your comment an answer, I would mark it accepted.

Comment: No can do ... your question has already been closed as a duplicate.